# Access SQL - group data by week for current month ( 4 or 5 weeks only per month )

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I need your help with this table please.

```
GROUP BY DatePart("ww",[date]), statisticsABC.Date
HAVING (((statisticsABC.Date) Between [STARTDATE] And [ENDDATE]));
```

I used `DatePart("ww",[date])` but it shows me data like this:

[image: Please see the picture to understand my question]

Comment: Define your week. A 31-day month can span six weeks by the usual calendar week approach.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the date field from the grouping:

```sql
...
WHERE 
    statisticsABC.Date Between [STARTDATE] And [ENDDATE]
GROUP BY 
    DatePart("ww",statisticsABC.Date)
```